# How to grab a random MYSQL Column Value using PHP and echo it?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im wondering how i would do this with mysqli and i need to pull the column name userKey and echo it in to a variable i tried searching for how to do this but i cant find anything if anyone could help it would be great!

Comment: your title and question contradict themselves

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Title: *"How to grab a **random** MYSQL Column using PHP and echo it?"*  and the question: *"and i need to pull the column name userKey"*. Edit: same difference.

Comment: sorry i ment to put column ill change it

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col_x='key' ORDER BY RAND()` ought to do it then, with an optional LIMIT.

Comment: so what exactly do i type?

Comment: $randomkey = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE col_x='userKey' ORDER BY RAND()"); would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with php mysqli:

```
$query=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT userKey FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10")or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbconect));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo $row['userKey'];
}
//you can change the limit in the mysqli
```

code not checked fyi